# What does empty destructor do?

Tags: c++, destructor

I heard that empty destructor doesn't do anything and calling it doesn't remove the object.
But in the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>


class a
{
public:
    ~a() 
    {}
std::set <int> myset;
};

int main()
{
a object;
object.myset.insert(55);
object.~a();
object.myset.insert(20);
std::cout << object.myset.size();
}
```

I get:
"*** glibc detected *** /.app: double free or corruption (fasttop):" and then "ABORT".

If it matters I have c++11 flag enabled. So what does empty constructor actually do? It does something and I read it doesn't.

Comment: The issue is with `object.~a();` do not manually call the destructor.

Comment: I don't want to do it, I just want to know what does destructor actually do.

Comment: Basicly it free the memory of the object back to to the system. All member variable destructor  are also called by this code behind the sense.

Comment: @user1873947: the destructor destroys all member variables. The main time you'd invoke a dtor directly is in conjunction with using placement new.

Comment: Add a class B as your member variable, instead of set. Use cout in constructor/destructor of B and A to see what exactly happens.

Comment: A *trivial* destructor does nothing, any other destructor does something even if the code looks like it does nothing

Comment: @andre is member variable like `int` , `char`, ... have destructors also ? I think destructors are present only for object and class not for primitive data types.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your destructor may look empty, but it's actually destructing the member variables. In this case, it's destructing `myset`, so the subsequent `insert(20)` is crashing.

If your class had no non-POD member variables then the empty destructor would truly do nothing.

Comment: Maybe.  If your class had a base class, or virtual functions, the destructor might do something as well.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know, it deletes member variables. Thanks, I will accept it.

Comment: @JamesKanze: True, but I'm assuming OP already knows that part. His example here has no inheritance.

Comment: @user1873947 It doesn't delete them (and that's not what Kevin wrote); it destructs them.

Comment: @user1873947: What James said. "delete" refers to the `delete` operator, which destructs the object and then deallocates the memory the object was in. In this case, you're only destructing, and a good thing too because your object is on the stack rather than allocated on the heap.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/582/lily-ballard) what is non-POD , i did not get that, please elabborate.

Comment: @GeekyCoder POD is Plain Old Data, which are types that have no constructor, destructor, or virtual member functions. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c

Answer (score 6):

Your question mentions a couple different issues.

First, there's the error message.  The "Double free" is probably because the destructor is getting called twice: once by you, and once by the C++ runtime when the variable is no longer in scope (at the closing brace of your `main` function).

Second, there's your question about the empty destructor not removing the object.  Indeed it does not remove the object from memory, but it DOES destroy its member variables.  So after your manual call to the destructor, the memory for `object` is still allocated, but `myset` is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

Destructor is called when going out of scope. I would highly recommend not calling the destructor, and then attempting to access members or member functions of the parent class. Since your class has member variables `myset`, it's deallocating those when being manually called, hence the segmentation error.

Think of the destructor as the "clean up" when you're absolutely done with your object. Under no circumstances should you call it manually.

Pseudocode:

```
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass() {
    std::cout << "Constructor" << std::endl;
  }

  ~MyClass() {
     std::cout << "~Destructor" << std::endl;
   }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   MyClass myClass;
   return 0;
}
```

You should see this output:

`Constructor`

`~Destructor`

As you can see, no manual call is needed.

Comment: Yeah that's what I said, guy. "Since your class has member variables myset, it's deallocating those when being manually called"